# Can I use Amazon S3 for Storing Media(images,audio video) and docs(pdfs,excel,text) for cheap solution?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

Basically I want to create **mobile app (android)** which stores users data like Media(audio,video,image),docs(pdfs,excel,text,etc) on server so that user can retrieve/edit data any time. Every User Given 1 GB of space to store data on server. consider I am having thousands of user. we will be using LAMP stack for all web service kind work.

1. Can I use Amazon s3 along with EC2 for above problem ?
2. Does Amazon S3 is cheaper for such **large amount of data storage** ?
3. **will Amazon EC2 cost more if I don't use s3 and store everything on Ec2 instance**?

I am searching for effective and cheap solution, I don't know much about AWS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, S3 is a good solution for storage - fast, reliable, redundant and cheap.
2. Yes, overall it will be cheaper to store files on S3 than EC2 - but see #3 below.
3. Amazon EC2 is fixed cost for a certain configuration. If you offload some of you storage to S3 (which is often a good idea), it might prevent you from having to use a bigger (or more) EC2 instances, so it *might* cost you more if you don't use S3 for storage, but really depends on your usage.

Answer (score 2):

S3 can be purchased in cost effective manner. for example, You can opts for Glacier Storage/Standard Storage on S3. Which is cheaper than Reduced Redundancy Storage on S3 to save money.

S3 is cheapest service among all AWS Services, everything else is costlier compare to S3.